# How to add an element to end of Linked-List in C?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, nodes

I am working on a flight program but I can't add new routes for the program. Here are my codes, how to fix it? 
I want users to type datas such as flight source, destination and number. 
How can i take datas from user and storage that informations. Thanks for help to everyone :/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

struct flightnode {

    char source[20];
    char destination[20];
    struct flightnode *next;
};


struct flightnode* head = NULL;
struct flightnode* temp = NULL;
struct flightnode* k = NULL;

char source[20];
char destination[20];

/*void addtoend(char x) {

    struct node* newtemp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct flightnode));
    newtemp->source = x;
    newtemp->next = NULL;



}*/

int main() {

    head = (struct flightnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct flightnode));
    temp= (struct flightnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct flightnode));

    printf("for source: \n");
    scanf(" %s", &source);
    printf("for dest: \n");
    scanf(" %s",&destination);


    strcpy(head->source,source);
    strcpy(temp->destination,destination);

    printf("source : %s\n", head->source);
    printf("dest : %s", temp->destination);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you know how to construct a pointer to the last node in the list? Do you know how to iterate over a list? These are basic operations on linked lists, and you must master them before you attempt `addtoend`.

Comment: i dont know how to use linked list actually .

Comment: A couple of side comments: `struct node` isn't defined. I assume you mean `flightnode` in that case. `source` is an array of characters, but you're attempting to assign a single character with `newtemp->source = x`.

Comment: @sagopa__ Why does the function parameter has the type char?! What are you trying to append to the list?

Comment: [C linked lists](https://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists).

Comment: my friend has upload that. Apparently, he didn't upload it right.My problem is.. im new at the linked list thing and i dont know how to use it for storage char data.As i said im programming for flight informations but i dont know how to save that datas in the linked list.I searched a lot of sites but i couldn't find an example of a linked list program for character files. so pls help me im exhausted for searching an example

Answer (score 0):

Under the list header file #include use adjList.push_back(data) where adjList is the name of the linkedlist

Comment: also use #include<vector> header file

Comment: You're referring to C++, not C. Op's question is about C.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's unclear what you want with `newtemp->source = x;`. You can't assign a single char to an array of char... I'll assume it's a string...

Anyway - the classic way to add to the end of a linked list is:

```
void addtoend(struct flightnode **p, char* x) 
{
    // Construct the new node
    struct node* newtemp = malloc(sizeof *newtemp);
    strcpy(newtemp->source, x);
    newtemp->next = NULL;

    // Is the list empty?
    if (*p == NULL)
    {
        // yes... so the new node will be the new head
        *p = newtemp;
        return;
    }

    // Iterate to last node
    struct flightnode *tmp = *p;    
    while(tmp->next != NULL) tmp = tmp->next;

    // Add new node after last node
    tmp->next = newtemp;
}
```

and call it like:

```
addtoend(&head, "Hello");
```

And a complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct flightnode {

    char source[20];
    char destination[20];
    struct flightnode *next;
};



void addtoend(struct flightnode **p, char* x) 
{
    // Construct the new node
    struct flightnode* newtemp = malloc(sizeof *newtemp);
    strcpy(newtemp->source, x);
    newtemp->next = NULL;

    // Is the list empty?
    if (*p == NULL)
    {
        // yes... so the new node will be the new head
        *p = newtemp;
        return;
    }

    // Iterate to last node
    struct flightnode *tmp = *p;    
    while(tmp->next != NULL) tmp = tmp->next;

    // Add new node after last node
    tmp->next = newtemp;
}

void printList(struct flightnode *p)
{
    printf("---- LIST ----\n");
    while(p)
    {
        printf("%s\n", p->source);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("--------------\n");
}

int main() {

    struct flightnode* head = NULL;

    addtoend(&head, "Hello");
    printList(head);

    addtoend(&head, "world");
    printList(head);

    addtoend(&head, "have");
    printList(head);

    addtoend(&head, "a");
    printList(head);

    addtoend(&head, "nice");
    printList(head);

    addtoend(&head, "day");
    printList(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
---- LIST ----
Hello
--------------
---- LIST ----
Hello
world
--------------
---- LIST ----
Hello
world
have
--------------
---- LIST ----
Hello
world
have
a
--------------
---- LIST ----
Hello
world
have
a
nice
--------------
---- LIST ----
Hello
world
have
a
nice
day
--------------
```

Comment: @sagopa__ It's working fine - see https://ideone.com/yuxNDe If you get errors then you didn't copy it correct or some other parts of your code is causing the error